# How would add an aggregate function to show total price and quantity for a report

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my code so far

```
SELECT
customer.customer_id AS "ID",
order_item.quantity AS "Quantity",
TO_CHAR (tree.price, 'FML999.99') AS "Total Price"
FROM 
customer
INNER JOIN
order_form ON order_form.customer_id = customer.customer_id
INNER JOIN
order_item ON order_item.order_id = order_form.order_id
INNER JOIN
batch ON batch.tree_id = order_item.tree_id
INNER JOIN
tree ON tree.id = batch.tree_id
WHERE order_item.order_id = '00000072'
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID        Quantity  Total Price       
------    ---------- -----------------
C93          2       £56.             
C93          1      £27.4            
C93          1       £47.
```

How would i get this to show as

REQUIRED OUTPUT :

```
ID       Quantity Total Pice       
------ ---------- -----------------
C93 ,         4,     £130.4
```

All responses will be very appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation; `group by` clause has to contain columns that aren't aggregated.

```
  SELECT customer.customer_id AS "ID",
         SUM (order_item.quantity) AS "Quantity",
         TO_CHAR (SUM (tree.price), 'FML999.99') AS "Total Price"
    FROM customer
         INNER JOIN order_form ON order_form.customer_id = customer.customer_id
         INNER JOIN order_item ON order_item.order_id = order_form.order_id
         INNER JOIN batch ON batch.tree_id = order_item.tree_id
         INNER JOIN tree ON tree.id = batch.tree_id
   WHERE order_item.order_id = '00000072'
GROUP BY customer.customer_id
```